# "mvn dependency:tree" - is there an equivalent available for "verbose" output?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a use-case where we want to know all the versions that a Maven project gets per dependency tree even if they are omitted.

Per *maven-dependency-plugin* documentation the "verbose" option has been discontinued since Maven 3 and "tree" Mojo of dependency goal is not more able to show the omitted dependencies.

I am using Maven 3.5.0 and tried using an additional installation of Maven 2.x, but that yields compatibility issues with Java 8 apps.

Is there a way to get verbose dependency tree output in Maven 3?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use

```
mvn dependency:tree -X
```

which [produces the debug output](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html).

Otherwise stated in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) about `verbose` -

> Notice this feature actually uses Maven 2 algorithm and may [give wrong
> results when used with Maven 3](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-dependency-tree/).

**Edit**: As pointed by Brad in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416236/mvn-dependencytree-is-there-an-equivalent-available-for-verbose-output/46417483?noredirect=1#comment116016968_46417483), the `verbose` flag has been  [reintroduced for the `3.2.0`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-644) release and further.

Comment: Is there a way to print dependency conflicts?

Comment: Looks like -Dverbose=true will work in maven-dependency-plugin 3.2.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-644

Comment: @BradCupit Indeed looks like to me as well. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be ready for 'prime time' yet. It frequently hangs, seemingly whilst trying to do lots of network activity.

Answer (score 2):

The `-verbose` flag was updated in version 3.2.0 of the Maven Dependency Plugin to work correctly with Maven 3, per [MDEP-644](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-644).

Using this version of the plugin or newer will ensure that it returns correct results.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```