# mvn dependency:tree hangs trying to read repository

Tags: maven, sdkman

```
$ mvn --version
```

> Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)

> Maven home: /home/redacted/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current

> Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc., runtime: /home/redacted/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.1.fx-zulu

> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8

> OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-91-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Running the following command never finishes and it appears to be hung.

```
mvn -X dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

The last lines of the debug log report:

> [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/

> [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/

I'm curious why running a dependency tree command is causing maven to try to hit the tesla.io repository on port 8081.

Is there some way to tell `dependency:tree` to skip this repository (or to configure some timeout and skip all repositories that are unreachable within some specified timeout limit)?

How can I trace the reason why `dependency:tree` is trying to read from the tesla repository?

Comment: Following as I've seen this exact same behavior after upgrading spring-boot-starter from 2.5.5 to 2.6.1.

Comment: I suppose you have either a settings.xml with appropriate configuration...

Comment: For my case, with spring-boot... removing the -Dverbose flag, allows the dependency tree to complete.... but I need to use the flag for another reason.

Comment: @khmarbaise - No. I don't have a ~/.m2/settings.xml. Everything is default configuration. I did install maven using SdkMan though. Maybe I'll tag that project too.

Comment: If don't have a settings.xml where have you configured to consume tesla.io from ? wihtin your pom file? Because it looks like an internal repository manager which should be configured in your settings.xml ....

Comment: Exactly. That's what I'm wanting to figure out. There's nothing in my pom.xml with that configuration. And, these appear to be for snapshots. I did confirm as mentioned by @SteveGreenslade that removing the verbose flag does allow the goal to execute successfully. Notice this answer links to documentation stating that using the verbose flag on 3.5+ could cause errors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46417483/328275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above by SteveGreenslade, and per the `maven-dependency-plugin` [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-dependency-plugin-2.5.1/tree-mojo.html#verbose):

verbose:

Deprecated. in 2.5

Whether to include omitted nodes in the serialized dependency tree.

- Type: boolean
- Since: 2.0-alpha-6
- Required: No User Property: verbose
- Default: false

Removing the `-D verbose` flag after upgrading the plugin above version 2.5 fixed the problem for me.